# Difference between "in the bun" and "on the bun"?

Tags: prepositions

I was thinking how would you imagine the following sentences?

> Put the diced onions **in** the bread bun(s?).
>
> Put the diced onions **on** the bread bun.

Does the second one depicts the sandwich as perpandicular to the level ground and onions on the top of the bottom bread? Does it have anything to do with the geometry of the sandwitch?

Also, should the first one be in plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that a bun is **not** the same thing as a sandwich. A bun looks like this:
[image]

A sandwich is made of two slices of bread with some filling sandwiched between the two slices: an open sandwich is only one slice of bread, with the filling on top. A slice of bread looks like this:

[image]

Now we are clear what a bun is, we can look at the singular/plural issue. If there is one bun, you say **bun**. If you have more than one bun, you say **buns**. The only kind of **buns** with no singular is when you use it as a colloquial term for a woman's bottom, and she probably wouldn't let you put onions on her buns.

If you cut a bun horizontally in two, place the onions on the bottom half and then replace the top half, the onions are **in** the bun. If you do not cut the bun and you sprinkle the onions on the top of the bun, the onions are **on** the bun.

In this picture, the sesame seeds are **on** the bun, and the patty, cheese, salad and tomatoes are **in** the bun.

[image]

*Note: no animals were harmed in the making of this picture: it's a veggie burger*

Answer (score 1):

You have to put things *on* (the outside of) a piece of bread.

> Put the diced onions on the bread bun

Regarding the bread itself, you could only use *in* if you tore a hole into the bread and put something in. Or if something is an ingredient.

> There are raisins *in* the bread.

While you would put onions *on* the bottom bun, you can use *in* when referring to ingredients in the assembled food item.

> There are onions *in* the hamburger.